# Read file form txt and perform operation by name in geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a txt that contains in each line a sentence like this:

```
INT_ASTIK_EAS
ER_ASTOM_ASTIK
and so on.
```

I want to ask for a directory of the main folder that contains the subfolders that each contain the `ASTIK.shp`, then the `EAS.shp`, then the `ASTOM.shp`, etc

`INT` means to perform an intersection with this code where in this case should involve `ASTIK` and `EAS` shapefiles.

```
inte_s=gpd.overlay(ASTIK,EAS,how='intersection')
```

and check if it has no info in the attribute table. Then go the to the other line and `catch on` the meaning of the line and perform `erase` between the two named shapefiles. Find them and perform it.How do i do that without making a lot of conditions and line by line: like

```
directory=input('Insert dir of the main folder')

    If 'INT' in firstline of txt in directory and ASTOM and EAS:
    perform interesection between those.
```

i don't think the only way is to create hundreads of if conditions that will probably never be valid. How should i do it?

THE LAST VERSION

```
import os
import fiona
rootdir = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\a' # path to your root directory you walk
sfiles = {} # a dictionary with all the .shp files
for entry in os.listdir(rootdir):
    dirpath = os.path.join(rootdir, entry)
    if os.path.isdir(dirpath): 
        for file in os.listdir(dirpath): # Get all files in the subdirectories
            if file.endswith('.shp'): # If it's an .shp.
                filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
                sfiles[filepath[:-4]] = fiona.open(filepath)

action_dict = {'INT': 'intersection', 'ER': 'difference'}


directory=input('Insert dir of the main folder')
with open(input()) as txtfile: #insert directory of txt
    x = txtfile.readlines()
for line in x:
    action, shape1, shape2 = line.split('_')  # here line is ER_ASTOM_ASTIK or whatever line in your txt file
    if shape1 in sfiles and shape2 in sfiles:
        gpd.overlay(sfiles[shape1], sfiles[shape2], how=action_dict[action])
```

it doesn't probably perform the intersection or difference. how can i store its results in a variable because i have to do further process with the outcomes of every operation of every line.

Comment: Do know how to do the erase process? i tried this but doesn't exist: `gpd.overlay(ASTIK,EAS,how='erase')`

Comment: Erase is called difference in geopandas: http://geopandas.org/set_operations.html

Comment: if i want to erase the part where two shapefiles have in common do i do symmetrical difference or just difference, can't tell the difference.

Comment: yes, in that case you want "symmetric_difference"

Comment: Can you help with the question?

Comment: `glob.glob` instead of `os.listdir` with the `file.endswith()` might be helpful. It has built in checking for specific filenames or regular expressions. Could you clarify where you are getting stuck?

Comment: In the part where it reads from the txt line by line and performs the operations with the mentioned in every line line shapefile pairs.I will add one extra final part it to the question.I think you will find the problem.it needs minimal correction i think.